Where/when is the buffer deleted in boost::asio::async_write(..) for the code provided
The code below works and works well for millions of messages on a daily basis. My question how/where does "msg" that is set up as a const vector get deleted if in fact that is what's happening? I do not do anything in the completion handler to remove it.
Thanks
The typedef is set in the tcp_connection class. The method is also part of the class.
int tcp_connection::writeToSocketAsync(std::string sMsg)
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<CharVec>  CharVecPtr;

    const std::vector<char> msg(sMsg.begin(), sMsg.end());
    
    CharVecPtr tmsg = boost::make_shared<CharVec>(msg);

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(*tmsg),
        boost::asio::transfer_all(),
        strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write,
            this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
}


The answer is: it doesn't get destroyed in async_write, because the caller owns it.
The code as written invokes Undefined Behaviour. The buffer must be kept alive until the operation completes: doc

buffers
One or more buffers containing the data to be written. Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the completion handler is called.

A typical solution works like this:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::placeholders;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct tcp_connection {
    tcp_connection(tcp::socket s) : socket_(std::move(s)) {}

    void connect(std::string const& host, std::string const& port) {
        tcp::resolver resolver(socket_.get_executor());
        asio::connect(socket_, resolver.resolve(host, port));
    }

    void writeToSocketAsync(std::string sMsg)
    {
        outgoing_message_ = std::move(sMsg);

        asio::async_write(                                    //
            socket_,                                          //
            asio::buffer(outgoing_message_),                  //
            bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, this, _1, _2) //
        );
    }

    void handle_write(boost::system::error_code const& ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "Sent " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string outgoing_message_;
};


With this "typical" solution won't it be prone to errors when sending more than one message consecutively?

@KIIV Of course. I'm focusing on the question. I probably have literally a hundred Asio answers on this site showing how to properly queue (full duplex) message buffers for in case that's relevant - but there's no indication from the OP to indicate either way. Likewise, I'm not jumping at tangents like managing the lifetime of the tcp_connection instance.

Where did it get destroyed? At the end of function scope.
It wouldn't matter much as you made copy into shared_ptr and it'll also get destroyed at the end of scope.
You could just have CharVecPtr tmsg = boost::make_shared(sMsg.begin(), sMsg.end());
You probably want to store copy of shared_ptr somewhere (maybe in the boost::bind as another parameter so it keeps one reference until that callback gets called and destroyed)

If I understand you correctly I don't need to do the extra step of creating a constant vector pointer because the shared pointer will hang around until the callback get called and destroyed. So by initializing a share_ptr to "CharVecPtr tmsg = boost::make_shared(sMsg.begin(), sMsg.end());" the data pointed to will hang around until the completion handler is called and destroyed? Storing a copy of the shared_ptr isn't really necessary then. Correct?

No, it's programming not magic, so unless you keep tmsg binded in that callback, reference counter reaches 0 and destroy object held inside at the end of function scope. (bind == it makes copy of it)

ok. To guarantee proper behavior, I will bind tmsg in with the other two arguments, and adjust the callback method signature accordingly. Once I am in the callback the use_count() call should return one(1). This would verify that the contents of the write buffer still exists. Then, once the callback is destroyed the contents of the buffer that was written will also be deleted.

I made "short" example without any boost, but it should be similar: https://godbolt.org/z/Gn5dzcP6j (it's for showing when it's constructed and destroyed...)
